# Put ViewModel in the right place

Tags: .net, xaml, silverlight, mvvm

I have a silverlight project. In App.xaml, we have

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then in `Assets/Styles.xaml`, we have the ViewModel.

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWeb.MyProj"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:localViewModels="clr-namespace:MyWeb.MyProj.ViewModels">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<localViewModels:MyProjViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
...
<telerikGridView:RadGridView
    ...
    ItemsSource="{Binding Schedules}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWeek, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">
```

Finally in MainPage.xaml.cs, we have

```
private MyProjViewModel viewModel;

public MyProjViewModel ViewModel
{
    get
    {
        if (this.viewModel == null)
        {
            this.viewModel = new MyProjViewModel();
        }
        return this.viewModel;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this.viewModel != value)
        {
            this.viewModel = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the constructor, we use the ViewModel as

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this.ViewModel;
    this.ViewModel = this.DataContext as MyProj;
}
```

Although it works, but I am not sure if it is the best structure to use ViewModel because it is placed in Styles.xaml. If not, how to correct it?

Comment: I would remove the ViewModel definition from Styles. Put it in the MainPage constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one particular instance of a ViewModel to be available for the entire lifecycle of the application, the you can define it in a Resource Dictionary, like you did (of course you will have to reference it from the resource dictionary and not use like you did in your question).

Better solution is to create it in the constructor of the view (without the definition in styles.xaml).

```
public MyProjectViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

public MainPage()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.ViewModel = new MyProjViewModel();
     this.DataContext = this.ViewModel;
}
```